# Allow People to Hide Slides in Read Only Mode

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

We distribute PowerPoint slides to educators who teach our content. We don't want people to modify the slides in any way so I have protected the slideshow with a password that restricts editing. Educators select 'Read Only' when the password prompt appears. The problem is that don't have the ability to hide slides in Read Only mode. This is a requirement. Is there any way to do this? Maybe using a VB Macro?